# chrome packaged apps and the contacts API

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app

After examination of the chrome packaged apps javascript API I couldn't find `navigator.contacts`. This is where I looked: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index

Does it exist?

I also found this cordova plugin - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/master/doc/index.md

Can this plugin be imported somehow to the chrome packaged apps framework? I do see an empty plugins folder in the example app. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cca plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts`